# How to determine public keys that were used to generate a multisig address?

Tags: multi-signature

How can I verify the public key that I provided was actually used to generate the multisig address I'm funding for say escrow?

Comment: You might want to differentiate between raw multisignature and P2SH multisignature. The former is deprecated and can't sensibly be used on the network anymore.

Answer (score 1):

A redeem script is generated along with the multisig address. The redeem script can be decoded at https://coinb.in/#verify (for example) to determine the address, the required number of signatures, and a list of the public keys with access. (It will also be used later to release the bitcoins.)